# How to Skip a field/component/sub-component without xmltag in Smooks

Tags: smooks

I want to process a baplie edi and however i don't need all the values coming in the EDI file. in such a case is there a way to skip a field/component/sub-component without the xmltag being displayed in the output unnecessarily.

Example,

I just need the sender identification and receipient indentification alone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally familiar with that message format, but you can tell the Smooks EDI reader (via the EDI mapping model) to "truncate" fields, segments etc. (see the docs). So, what you ask should be possible if the data is at the end (I think).

Comment: truncate will handle the empty incoming values but will generate the xml tags in the output

Comment: Hmmm .... that sounds wrong. Did you set the "truncate" flag on the parent field/segment etc? You might need to do that too.